# Check if df1 column contains df2 column strings

Tags: python, pandas, string, function

I have two dataframes. Df1 contains 'text' column (assume news article extracts) and df2 contains a 'name' column. I want to apply a function such that it creates a new boolean column 'C' in df1 to indicate if df1 'text' column contains specific df2 'name' column element. Both columns are objects.

df1

```
text
In contrast to other large markets in Asia, Vietnam saw a surge in installations as ...
... for water for industrial production and clean water consumption. .
Barry Kiely, CEO and co-founder of PrecisionBiotics Group, said,
UCAN Zipper USA (US), Keen Ching Industrial Co., Ltd. (Taiwan), Kao .
De plus, la croissance de l'industrie du vÃªtement crÃ©e des perspectives 
Workers depart the Samsung Electronics Vietnam Co. ... But trade experts said Vietnam
```

df2

```
Name
Keen Ching Industrial Co., Ltd.
Adidas Ltd.
Samsung Electronics Vietnam Co.
Nike co.
PrecisionBiotics Group
```

Here is what I tried but it threw me an error:

```
df1['C'] = df1.apply(lambda x: df2['name'] in x.text, axis=1)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not Series
```

Desired df1 C column

```
C
False
False
True
True
False 
True
```

Comment: Use `isin()` function

Comment: `df1['C'] = df1["text"].isin(df2["name"])`

Comment: @bigbounty Hello, thanks for your comment. Can you please elaborate? I'm a beginner in coding

Comment: It's better if you can give sample data

Answer (score 0):

`df2['name']` is the entire `Series` here, not an individual element.

Since you would like to check if `x.text` contains a specific element from `df2['name']`, please use that element - for example, `df2['name'].iloc[0]`.

**Example:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl'], 'name': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'e']})
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: df['name'].iloc[0] in x.text, axis=1)
```

will give -

```
 name text      C
0    a  abc   True
1    b  def  False
2    c  ghi  False
3    e  jkl  False
```

Or, if you'd like to check if any element from `df['name']` is present in text -

```
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: np.array([z in x.text for z in df['name']]).any(), axis=1)
```

will give -

```
  name text      C
0    a  abc   True
1    b  def   True
2    c  ghi  False
3    e  jkl  False
```

Answer (score 0):

After several readings, I will assume the following:

- `df1['text'`
- `df2['name']` contain keywords (one per row) that you want to research in each row of `df1['text']`
- `df1['C']` will be true iif at least one keyword is found in the text of same row

So for any row of `df1`, you will have to test all the rows from `df2` (or at least until a match). You could use:

```
df1['C'] = df1['text'].apply(lambda x: df2['name'].apply(lambda y: y in x).any())
```

With the provided sample data, it gives as expected:

```
                                                text      C
0  In contrast to other large markets in Asia, Vi...  False
1  ... for water for industrial production and cl...  False
2  Barry Kiely, CEO and co-founder of PrecisionBi...   True
3  UCAN Zipper USA (US), Keen Ching Industrial Co...   True
4  De plus, la croissance de l'industrie du vÃªte...  False
5  Workers depart the Samsung Electronics Vietnam...   True
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer! Everything looks good except for df2['name'] contains one element per row but each element may not be a single string but a full name consists of first and last name. Does your answer still apply to this situation?

Comment: @MatthiasGallagher: Please edit your question with a sample data. It would be both simpler and more sure for the tests...

Comment: @MatthiasGallagher: Answer edited too :-) . It works...